# Change font color of a column in a matrix

Tags: color, matrices, columns

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c & d \\
a & b & c & d \\
a & b & c & d \\
a & b & c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

\end{document}
```

What I want to do is change the color of the first and third column to red.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to automate this process for an entire column, then you need to have access to the column specification. This is not possible via [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s [`*matrix` environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26434/5764). Instead, use [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) and insert `\color{red}` in front of every entry using the `>{<prefix>}` specification:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array,xcolor}

\begin{document}

$
  A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b & c & d \\
    a & b & c & d \\
    a & b & c & d \\
    a & b & c & d
  \end{bmatrix} \qquad
  \left[\begin{array}{@{} >{\color{red}}c c >{\color{red}}c c @{}}
    a & b & c & d \\
    a & b & c & d \\
    a & b & c & d \\
    a & b & c & d
  \end{array}\right] = A
$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

A Little bit easier!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\[
A =
\def\b{b}
\def\d{d}
\def\a{\color{red}a}
\def\c{\color{red}c}
\begin{bmatrix}
\a & \b & \c & \d \\
\a & \b & \c & \d \\
\a & \b & \c & \d \\
\a & \b & \c & \d \\
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sure the OP made the matrix A have similar rows out of ease for a minimal example. In general, how would your suggestion be "easier" if the columns had arbitrary content in them?

Comment: @Werner: I don't claim to offer something generic. My assumption was this is what the OP needs, inherently. Actually, I was not as sure as you are! :D

Comment: Werner is right. However, thank you for your answer @Roboticist. It can be useful for another purpose !

Answer (score 2):

Based on [How to color math symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21598) or [Simpler way to add color to equations in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280598) (*I googled "math color latex"*).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
\textcolor{red}{a} & b & \textcolor{red}{c} & d \\
\textcolor{red}{a} & b & \textcolor{red}{c} & d \\
\textcolor{red}{a} & b & \textcolor{red}{c} & d \\
\textcolor{red}{a} & b & \textcolor{red}{c} & d \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted an automatic way to change the color of the columns (like the accepted answer), but thank you for your answer !